# Arduino - Covert to value to DEC HEX Value

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a serial event that reads a HEX byte. This is stored as INT representing the HEX value. I need to convert this back to a Dec value.

Example:

Serial is sent 0x20 - stored as INT 32 - I want to convert this to INT 20

I have tried the following but it Prints OK but wont convert. How do I get it too.

Sudo Code:

```
int from_ser;
int new_value;
Serial.println(from_ser); // Prints 32
Serial.println(from_ser,HEX); // Prints 20 ( The value we want!)
new_value = (from_ser,HEX);
Serial.println(new_value); // Prints 16 - Why !!!
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Serial.println(from_ser,HEX); // Prints 20 ( The value we want!)
```

This is a feature of the println method on Serial.  There's code that checks the second argument when deciding how to format the value in the first argument.  Note that HEX is just a manifest constant with the value 16.

```
new_value = (from_ser,HEX);
```

This is a completely different type of expression.  In C++, you can have two expressions separated by a comma, and the code will evaluate both expressions and result in the value of the second one.  Here `HEX` is the second value, and it's just a name for `16`, so `new_value` is assigned to the integer 16.

Comment: Thanks. That make sense! But how do i make new value = 20 ?

Comment: The value is what the value is.  How you choose to display it is a formatting choice you make when you print it.  The value is simultaneously 32 decimal and 20 hexadecimal and 40 octal and 10000 binary.  You don't convert from one of those to another, you decide which base you want when you display it.

Comment: Thanks I want to create a new verible that stores 20.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you want.  I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding on here.  What is your goal?  What do you mean when you say you want a variable that stores 20?  Are you looking for a way to convert the integer to a string that contains the hexadecimal representation of the value?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting as decimal or hex is an operation on OUTPUT.   It does not affect the actual value of the variable, or give an integer with a different value.   It simply formats the output differently.   So your question of "converting" the value is meaningless.   Simply send the variable by whatever means is specified.

In C++, the comma operator in the expression `a , b` evaluates `a` and discards the result, then gives the result of evaluating `b`.   So `new_value = (from_ser, HEX)` gives the value of `HEX`.  By outputting `new_value`, you are demonstrating that `HEX` has the value `16`.

Answer (score -1):

0x20 (hexadecimal) is 32 (decimal). Why would you want 20? That would be wrong.
What would you do with 0xFF then?

Comment: i need to keep serial format the same. i have clock set value that wants decimal values but everything needs to be sent as hex over serial.

Comment: @Jeremy and what would you do with a hex value that has letters in it? are you sure you know what you are doing? If 0x20 is 20 what is 0xFF in your opinion?